# `matlab` extracting blue channel from 3D image into a 2D monochrome matrix

Tags: image, matlab, matrix, filter, imshow

I have an RGB image of which i want to extract the blue channel by doing

```
    new_image = image(:,:,3);
```

this is now a 2 dimensional matrix, however I want to apply a filter on it using the `filter2()` function and displaying this filtered image using `image()` or `imshow()`. when using the `imshow()` to display the image, the display is grayscale. how can i arrange this so that i will have blue filtered monochrome image?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access RGB channels in an image in MATLAB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25165707/access-rgb-channels-in-an-image-in-matlab)

Answer (score 0):

Either put it back into an RGB matrix with the R and G channels set to zero or create a colormap.

Comment: but filter2 doesnt work on RGB 3 D matrices right? i need to eliminate R and G completely

Comment: Before imshow or image you should have `img = zeros(size(original_image));  img(:,:,3) = filtered_image;`